# Can I build a Google map for sharing, that does not have the share/embed option built in?

Tags: google-maps

I am currently using `maphub` for maps on my website that the members of my group can use. The share and embed option is easily removed from map hub but I would prefer to use Google Maps. The issue is once I make the set of maps, I want them to be locked to my website only, and not have the share/embed option so that they can be shared to non members. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to a JavaScript API map? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: Also note that you can secure your API key by restricting it to your own domain so that it can't be (mis)used anywhere else, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key

Comment: Thank you Evan,Apologies for taking so long to get back to you, I have been unwell with a very chest infection, I'll have a look at these tips now.

Comment: No worries! Hope those links help, keep me posted thx!